# How do you say "muscle fever" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I've heard only "envaramiento", so people say in Spanish

> Estoy envarado por haber nadado ayer.

Wikipedia says it's said *agujetas*, which I've never heard. Is there another non-medical term for muscle fever?

Comment: "agujetas" is indeed the usual word in Spain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to RAE **agujetas** is correct, and it is a term I have heard several times the day after playing an intense football match, skiing,..

> pl.  Molestias dolorosas que pueden sentirse en los músculos algún tiempo después de realizar un esfuerzo no habitual y reiterado.

**Dolor muscular** is self explanatory.

The medical term would be **mialgia**, and in English is **myalgia**, origin on the greek words myos(muscle)+algos(pain)

**Alternatives:**

*Agarrotar*:

> prnl. Dicho de un miembro: Quedarse rígido o inmóvil por efecto del frío o por otra causa.

musculo agarrotado

*Engarrotar*

> 1. tr. Dicho del frío: Causar entumecimiento de los miembros. U. t. c. prnl.

musculo engarrotado

*Envaramiento* it is a new word for me but is correct:

Envaramiento es la acción de envarar o envararse

> envarar.
>    (De en- y vara).
>   1. tr. Entorpecer, entumecer o impedir el movimiento de un miembro. U. m. c. prnl.

*Entumecer/entumecido* is repeated on these definitions so it is correct.

In my opinion all these alternatives should be used when is painfull and makes it hard to move.

An alternative could be *punzada* or *tirón* muscular, but it is usually used when the pain is strong and short:

> . Dolor agudo, repentino y pasajero, pero que suele repetirse de tiempo en tiempo.

An example: *Desde que tuve el accidente tengo unas punzadas en la espalda que no me dejan dormir.*

About agujetas:

In fact several Catalan speakers use it in catalan (*agulletes*) but it is not correct, and this is due to the Spanish influence (*agujetas*).

Comment: But how do Spaniards say? "Tengo agujetas", "Me siento con agujetas", "Estoy agujetas"? or do I need another verb?

Comment: @c.p. Yes we say _"Tengo agujetas"_. The other two forms are either incorrect or sound very awkward.

Answer (score 5):

In Mexico we say "entumido" (numb) or "adolorido" (in pain). I'm not sure where in Mexico they say the former, but in Guadalajara we say the latter. For example,

```
Estoy adolorido porque fui ayer al gimnasio.
```

Comment: Today I learned that "adolorido" is more or less the same word as "dolorido", but I thought it didn't exist.

Comment: Perhaps "dolorido" is the correct word but in Mexico we render it as "adolorido"? Small deformations like this happen pretty often.

Comment: No, no, I meant no sarcasm. Both words exist, at least following the RAE dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

There might be regional terms for that, but I've never heard anyone say "envaramiento" or "agujetas". A more regionally neutral way to say it would be

```
Me duelen los músculos por haber nadado ayer
```

Comment: Agujetas is a common term in Spain for sore muscles the day after you do a lot of exercise. Envaramiento never heard of, but it probably is a local term from a Latin American country.

Comment: @Muttley75 here in Peru we use `dolor muscular`, never heard of `agujetas` nor `envaramiento`.

Comment: Dolor muscular does sound pretty region neutral. Agujetas is really common in Spain, as others have said

Answer (score 3):

In Mexico, `agujetas` is not so common, you must say:

> Estoy entumido.

Comment: Don't you mean "entumecido"? According to the RAE, entumido means "tímido" in México:
entumido, da.
1. adj. Méx. tímido.

Comment: @pHonta What in that entry RAE says is sheer nonsense. *Entumido*, as in the answer, is correct (not exactly scientifically right, but correct). To see that, go to stright to the verb *entumir*: "Dicho de un miembro o de un músculo: Entorpecerse por haber estado encogido o sin movimiento, o por compresión de algún nervio."

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation :)